# How to redirect all lines not containing specific text to a text file?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

Getting a flood of 'Dropping' error messages from the kernel that can fill the HD quickly. I'd like to filter them out before they reach the log file. What is wrong with this syntax?

```
myprogram >(grep -v Dropping) > myprogram.log 2>&1 &
```

It seems to stop the output. Also tried various things using 'grep |' without success.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do `myprogram 2>&1 | grep -v Dropping > myprogram.log`

Comment: You're getting kernel messages in your userspace app?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes

Comment: @jacknad: how? .

Comment: @WilliamPursell tried that syntax earlier and again now, but nothing

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk good question - i'll have to look

Comment: How can we test? Can you write a sample ` myprogram` like `printf "Output %s\n" {1..20} | sed 's/.*[246]$/Dropping.../'` and test your results?

Comment: @WilliamPursell that actually worked. if there is any issue with the start script on this platform it resets the env variables on the hw which had to also be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if "myprogram" use STDIN or STDERR to print "Dropping", anyway, you can use:

```
myprogram 2>&1 | grep -v Dropping > myprogram.log
```